# how to use django-admin.py makemessages --all

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create messagefile in my django project.

for this, i just wrote this into my home view function:

```
def startpage(request):
   # Translators: This message appears on the home page only
   output = _("Welcome to my site.")
```

and in settings.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = [
   ('de', _('German')),
   ('en', _('English')),
   ('fr', _('French')),
   ('es', _('Spanish')),
   ('pt', _('Portuguese'))
]
```

and created `locale` directory inside my app.

now I am inside my app tree and giving this command:

```
django-admin.py makemessages --all
```

it is spitting out this

```
#!C:\workspace\newsportal\venv_np\Scripts\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'django==1.6','django-admin.py'
__requires__ = 'django==1.6'
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.run_script('django==1.6', 'django-admin.py')
```

and NOT creating messagefiles inside `locale`.

I tried with:

```
python manage.py makemessages --all
```

but it cannot find `manage.py` because i am inside my app, not in project tree. how is it done normally?

Comment: Have you set the locale path location in settings? `LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
)`

Comment: i created already ``locale`` dir inside my app and i am commanding from there, it should directly find it actually, shouldnot it? @cor

Comment: I dont't think so... I would try that

Comment: @cor i would want to have different translations for each app, so do i have to give all paths inside ``LOCALE_PATHS`` then? it doesnot make much sense to me :(

Comment: No, just the locale folder path. I also recommend you installinig django-rosetta.

Comment: i just want to create messagefile just for this app only, not project-wide. is it possible? @cor

Comment: Yes, but you need to append its path to `LOCALE_PATHS`. For example: `LOCALE_PATHS = (     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "yourapp/locale"), )`

Comment: @cor oh ok. thanks man. now it seems to be working. i just need the gettext tool for windows. heading for it;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need to add your locale directory paths to `LOCALE_PATHS`. For example:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "yourapp/locale"), 
]
```

Once you have included some text to be translated in your project, just execute this command for each language you want to translate. In your case:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
django-admin.py makemessages -l en
django-admin.py makemessages -l fr
django-admin.py makemessages -l es
django-admin.py makemessages -l pt
```

Then translate all the texts and compile them. I recommend to use [django-rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta) for this purpose, which is a Django application that eases the translation process of your Django projects.

```
django-admin.py makemessages --all
```

Everything should work now

Comment: thanks, I had to create ``<language>`` folder by hand like ``de``. but now working like a charm