# How to integrate multi-languages support by creating language files in Django 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, translation, arabic, django-2.0, makemessages

I want to create a **Django 2.0** powered website(including auto generated Admin site) that should support multiple languages.

For now I only want to keep 2 languages **English** and **Arabic**.

I read number of tutorials articles on web to use django-admin's **makemessages** and **compilemessages** commands to generate language files(.po files) & compile .mo files(generated by **makemessages** command).

But I did not get any specific solution regarding this integration using **Django2.0** and still I am facing the issue.

Can anyone please help me in solving this problem.

And also suggest how will I make it for **English** to **Arabic** translation.

Comment: Considering a [poor documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/) about this, it is not a low vote deserve question.

Comment: Thank you @AlexJolig. Yes, you are right as we can't find enough running/working example for this in a single place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now I got the solution of question, I am explaining it one by one.

As I want to translate my `model names`, `model field names`, some other `texts` available in modules and some `static/dynamic texts` present in my Django template.

Let's assume, I have the `models.py` and `index.html` as follows.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, help_text="First name of student", verbose_name="First name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Last name of student" , verbose_name="Last name")
    age = models.IntegerField(help_text="Age" , verbose_name="Age")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Student " + str(self.id) + " - " + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + created_by_user % (self.userid.username)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Student"
        verbose_name_plural = "Students"
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<h1> HOME PAGE </h1>
<h2> Django is nice </h2>
```

Now, I need to place translation texts in my `modules` and `templates`. 
I want my Django application to support `Arabic` & `English`.

1. Replace the code of `models.py` and `index.html` as follows.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, help_text = _("First name of student") , verbose_name =_("First name"))
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, help_text = _("Last name of student") , verbose_name =_("Last name"))
    age = models.IntegerField(help_text = _("Age") , verbose_name =_("Age"))

    def __str__(self):
        return "Student " + str(self.id) + " - " + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + created_by_user % (self.userid.username)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Student")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Students")
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
<h1> {% trans "HOME PAGE" %} </h1>
<h2> {% trans "Django is nice" %} </h2>
```

2. In settings.py, add the following(In my case I created folder named `locale` inside `BASE_DIR` you can choose another location and specify the location in `settings.py`).

   ```
   from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

   LOCALE_PATHS = (
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
   )

   LANGUAGES = (
       ('ar', _('Arabic')),
       ('en', _('English')),
   )

   MULTILINGUAL_LANGUAGES = (
       "en-us",
       "ar-ae",
   )
   ```
3. Run the `makemessages` command from any one of the 2 places based on the requirement as the command looks for the translation texts through all the child directories from which it is run.

   a. *Project's root directory* where `manage.py` resides.

   b. *App's root directory* where `models.py`, `views.py` resides.

   ```
   django-admin.py makemessages -l ar
   ```

   [Click here to check the language codes](https://gist.github.com/hygull/d8c5b0ff9654c48ed38d6bb34d86c197)
4. The above command will create a directory named `ar` inside `locale` directory with the following folder structure.

   ```
   .
   └── ar
       └── LC_MESSAGES
           └── django.po
   ```
5. In my case, `django.po` contains the following lines.

   ```
   # SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
   # Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
   # This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
   # FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
   #
   msgid ""
   msgstr ""
   "Project-Id-Version: \n"
   "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
   "POT-Creation-Date: 2017-12-24 12:34+0530\n"
   "PO-Revision-Date: 2017-12-24 11:56+0400\n"
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
   "Plural-Forms: nplurals=6; plural=n==0 ? 0 : n==1 ? 1 : n==2 ? 2 : n%100>=3 "
   "&& n%100<=10 ? 3 : n%100>=11 && n%100<=99 ? 4 : 5;\n"
   "Last-Translator: \n"
   "Language-Team: \n"
   "X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.11\n"

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:169
   msgid "First name of student"
   msgstr ""

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:169
   msgid "First name"
   msgstr ""

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:170
   msgid "Last name of student"
   msgstr ""

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:170
   msgid "Last name"
   msgstr ""

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:172
   msgid "Age"
   msgstr ""

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/templates/student_activity_reporter_app/index.html:93
   msgid "HOME"
   msgstr ""
   ...
   ...
   ```

   Now, fill the value of `msgstr` as the Arabic translation of the English string denoted by `msgid` as follows.

   ```
   # SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
   # Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
   # This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
   # FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
   #
   msgid ""
   msgstr ""
   "Project-Id-Version: \n"
   "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
   "POT-Creation-Date: 2017-12-24 12:34+0530\n"
   "PO-Revision-Date: 2017-12-24 11:56+0400\n"
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
   "Plural-Forms: nplurals=6; plural=n==0 ? 0 : n==1 ? 1 : n==2 ? 2 : n%100>=3 "
   "&& n%100<=10 ? 3 : n%100>=11 && n%100<=99 ? 4 : 5;\n"
   "Last-Translator: \n"
   "Language-Team: \n"
   "X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.11\n"

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:169
   msgid "First name of student"
   msgstr "الاسم الاول للمتهم"

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:169
   msgid "First name"
   msgstr "الاسم الاول"

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:170
   msgid "Last name of student"
   msgstr "اسم المتهم الأخير"

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:170
   msgid "Last name"
   msgstr "اسم الأخير"

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/models.py:172
   msgid "Age"
   msgstr "العمر"

   #: student_activity_reporter_app/templates/student_activity_reporter_app/index.html:93
   msgid "HOME"
   msgstr "الصفحه الرئيسيه"
   ```
6. Now run the `compilemessages` from the same directory as mentioned above, it will generate `django.mo` file.

   `django-admin.py compilemessages`

   The directory structure of `loacle` directory will look like this.

   ```
   .
   └── ar
       └── LC_MESSAGES
           ├── django.mo
           └── django.po
   ```
7. Start the development server using

   `python manage.py runserver`

   Visit [http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/) to view/access the `English` based Admin site. You will see the login page like below.
   [image: English login page]

   Visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/ar/admin/  to view/access the `Arabic` based Admin site. Now, you will see the login page like below.
   [image]

Add as many as translation texts to `modules` and `templates`, do proper configurations in `settings.py`, execute commands from proper place, choose proper language code and enjoy the `multilingual support` in your `Django powered` website.

**References:**

[how to use django-admin.py makemessages --all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720361/how-to-use-django-admin-py-makemessages-all/25721276)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/

[Localization: How to Create Language Files](https://djangobook.com/localization-create-language-files/)

Comment: Tnx for the details answer. But not sure why you haven't mentioned anything about urls.py. isn't that required to /ar/ work ?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to make any changes in `urls.py`.It will be taken care by django. As I can see in my case.